# Getting an specified object from array and take this as a variable

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, grep, output

Greetings stackoverflow community. I have a big problem. I can't get an content from an array to insert this content as a variable.

I mean: I have a array with many contents. Now i want to find a specified content from the array, but the output should be an variable. I hope the example code below should show what i mean, but i can't get it into an variable.

Please can anyone help me?

```sh
array=("first thing"
"second thing"
"third thing"
"fourth thing"
"fifth thing"
"...")

variable_from_array=(${array[@]} | grep "fourth thing")
```

Answer (score 3):

Either

```
echo "${array[3]}"
```

or

```
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
  [[ "${array[i]}" =~ ^fourth\ thing$ ]] && echo index: $i value: "${array[i]}"
done
```

Comment: If you don't need regular-expression-style pattern matching, `[[ "${array[i]}" = "fourth thing" ]]` would work.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer but the thing is i don't know the position of the content where im searching and this content, I'm searching, will be later used and i need this content in a variable.

Comment: Then instead of `echo "{array[i]}"`, do `variable="${array[i]}"`

Comment: Okay i think im stupid or i dont know. Can anyone send me the correct code to find the specific content from the array, with the function to save the output as a variable? And one information the contents in der array are domains and subdomains ^^